# popupbeforeposition event not firing after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

**In a nutshell..**

the popupbeforeposition event fires every time I open a popup on a page in my jquery mobile project UNTIL I use

`$.mobile.changePage(urlObj.hrefNoSearch, {data: postData, type: 'post', reloadPage: forceReload});`

to force a refresh of the current page, after-which the 'popupbeforeposition' event never fires.

**To elaborate and show my code..**

I have a page (`id="page_manage-buildings"`) in my jquery mobile project.

This page contains a link that opens a popup:

```
<a href="#manage_buildings_image_picker" data-rel="popup" data-role="none" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop">open popup</a>
```

The html for the 'manage_buildings_image_picker' popup contents is pretty straight forward:

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="manage_buildings_image_picker" data-transition="pop" class="ui-content" data-history="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="a" style="width:300px; height:150px;">
 ... popup contents here ...
 </div>
```

I have the 'pageinit' event bound to the '#page_manage-buildings' page and within that I am binding the 'popupbeforeposition' event to the 'manage_buildings_image_picker' popup, like so:

```
 $(document).on("pageinit", "#page_manage-buildings", function() {
    console.log('#page_manage-buildings page - pageinit event -- (only once for THIS page)');

    $( "#manage_buildings_image_picker" ).on({
         popupbeforeposition: function(event, ui) {                      
            console.log('popupbeforeposition event');

         }
    });

});
```

Everything works fine until I click a a button labeled 'refresh' that actually runs custom code to reload the current page using $.mobile.changePage to force a reload of the current page. (I need to retain a session variable that is passed from page to page).  Anyway, after I click on my refresh button, the 'popupbeforeposition' event is no longer fired when opening the 'manage_buildings_image_picker' popup.

This is the code that is executed when the 'refresh' button is clicked:

```
 convert_get_to_post($(location).attr('href'), true);

function convert_get_to_post(urlStr, forceReload){
    postData = new Object;
    var urlObj = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(urlStr);


    if(urlObj.search){
        // -- ensure any query string parameters are sent as post data
        var dataStr = urlObj.search.toString();
        dataStr = dataStr.replace(/^\?/,'');
        dataPairs = dataStr.split('&');
        //console.log('here is the dataPairs');
        //console.log(dataPairs);
        var avsessionFound=0;
        for (x in dataPairs) {
            dataPair = dataPairs[x];
            //console.log(dataPair);
            var dataSet = dataPair.split('=');
            //console.log('here is the dataSet');
            //console.log(dataSet);
            postData[dataSet[0]]=dataSet[1];
            if(dataSet[0]=='avsession'){
                avsessionFound=1;
                console.log('avsession found: '+dataSet[1]);
            }
        }
        if(avsessionFound==0){
            // inject the avsession value into the post data
            postData['avsession'] = $.jStorage.get('avsession', '');
        }
        //console.log('here is the postData');
        //console.log(postData);

        // send this request as a post
        $.mobile.changePage(urlObj.hrefNoSearch, {data: postData, type: 'post', reloadPage: forceReload});

    }else{
        // no query string to worry about jsut send this as a post with the avsession value injected
        postData['avsession'] = $.jStorage.get('avsession', '');
        $.mobile.changePage(urlObj.hrefNoSearch, {data: postData, type: 'post', reloadPage: forceReload});
    }

}
```

**UPDATE #1**

I changed the syntax of my ON binding and it fixed the 'popupbeforeposition' event issue but now the 'popupafterclose' event is firing twice when I close the popup.  I can deal with that but was wondering if it was caused from something obvious?

```
        $(document).on("pageinit", "#page_manage-buildings", function() {
            console.log('#page_manage-buildings page - pageinit event -- (only once for THIS page)');


            $(document).on("popupbeforeposition", "#manage_buildings_image_picker", function(event, ui) {
                console.log('*** popupbeforeposition event ***');                    
            });

            $(document).on("popupafterclose", "#manage_buildings_image_picker", function(event, ui) {
                console.log('*** popupafterclose event ***');                    
            });

        });
```

**Update #2**

Actually the code in update #1 caused the bind events to get bound pageview+(n-1) times where n is equal to the number of times that page was viewed.  This is because the events are bound at the document level (which stays the same in JQM) and is only ever updated as pages are loaded/unloaded.  I used Omar's suggestion and unbound the event with OFF befor binding the event which ensures there is only ever one event firing.

```
            $(document).off("popupbeforeposition", "#manage_buildings_image_picker").on("popupbeforeposition", "#manage_buildings_image_picker", function(event, ui) {
                console.log('*** popupbeforeposition event ***');                    
            });
```

binding events used only on a specific page at the document level seems messy and I would still like to know why it won't work when binding it to an element that exists within that page ??

Comment: maybe because you bind it to `pageinit`, as you mentioned, it fires once for the page.

Comment: @Omar I can see the output of `console.log('#page_manage-buildings page - pageinit event`... after refreshing so I know that the code which is supposed to bind the popupbeforeposition is getting executed.  If I moved it to pagebeforeshow then I might end up with multiple 'popupbeforeposition' events bound and I don't want that either.

Comment: Try `.off('popup.....').on('popup....')` or with `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: @Omar Updated my question if you have any thoughts?

Comment: try it this way `$(document).on("popupbeforeposition", "#manage_buildings_image_picker", function (event, ui) {
    console.log('*** popupbeforeposition event ***');
}).on("popupafterclose", "#manage_buildings_image_picker", function (event, ui) {
    console.log('*** popupafterclose event ***');
});` instead of binding it twice to document.

Comment: @Omar That took care of the double event.  Thanks!